# SharePoint custom content feature with Word Quick Parts and Document Information Panel

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, moss, infopath

I am creating a custom content type feature for MOSS that will also include a Word 2007 document as the document template. The same Word document will also have a *Document Information Panel* (DIP) and *Quick Parts* for all the fields in the content type.

The problem is that when my feature is deployed the Word document's Quick Parts no longer seem bound to the content type's columns in the Document Library. For example, if you:

1. Type a value into the Quick Part
2. Save the Word document to the document library
3. Look at the documents properties;

The value just typed is not listed. However if you use the DIP to specify the value (instead of the quick part) and then save it, it does get saved as metadata.

The "Document Information Panel Settings" screen for my content type is acting as if there is no InfoPath template. Sure enough if I re-upload (or create a new) InfoPath template, then the above problem goes away.

**How do I get this to work in my feature without having to do the manual step described above?**

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to define a custom template for the DIP and deploy that to the site, setting the content type to link to that template.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in a blog, but you have to use InfoPath... Here is the link: 
Using SharePoint Metadata in Word Documents – The Lookup Column

http://vspug.com/maartene/2009/03/13/using-sharepoint-metadata-in-word-documents-the-lookup-column-issue/